# I can't accept another answer after deleting the accepted answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, accepted-answer, deleted-answers

I asked a question, got a partial answer from A, came up with a complete answer, posted it and marked it as an answer.

But in between someone else (Person B) came up with a complete answer, before myself.

So I deleted my own answer and wanted to mark as an answer the most recent one, from person B.

Cannot!

There is no Mark as an answer link now. But my answer, marked as such, is deleted.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you link to that question?

Comment: Probably this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399299/assembly-specific-settings-not-loading-at-runtime

Answer (score 11):

The problem is solved for this particular case, and it's solved generally as users are unable to delete accepted answers now - they must first be un-accepted, then they can be deleted.

Answer (score 10):

If you Undelete your answer can you change the accepted answer? If so do that and then delete your answer again.

If this does not work, flag it for moderator attention.