# Can I literally delete my bad answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

This is not a duplicate of [completely-delete-my-deleted-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21323/completely-delete-my-deleted-answer), though, I'm guessing it's a duplicate of something else.

I just misread a question and put up a horribly stupid answer. I promptly deleted it, but 10K users can still see it. Is is possible to truly, utterly delete it so I don't look like a moron?

And yes, obviously I should read questions more thoroughly—mea culpa.

Comment: Why not edit it and make it correct? [That's what I have been told is best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38469/proper-way-to-correct-a-mistaken-answer)

Comment: The 10K+ users have seen it all anyway.  It's more important that the post is no longer visible to the general public.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14117/answers-quickly-deleted-by-owner-should-be-permanently-deleted

Comment: Not very tricky [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/906215/ratio-of-physically-deleted-posts) suggests that the SE deleted physically at most 0.07% of the posts ever posted.

Answer (score 9):

Not without getting a developer involved.

Normally I'd say you should edit the answer to correct it. But if there are other answers that already help the OP and you'd just be duplicating them, you might want to edit it to either remove content entirely (although that might encourage some to look at the edit history anyway :)) or leave a note fessing up to misreading the question.